# UIButton to not be clickable but to receive gestures

Tags: ios, uibutton, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a UIButton that I would like to be able to move with a `pan gesture`, but not be able to click it. What I want is when the user taps the button for the button to not change its appearance as if you just tap a view. Setting `isEnabled` to `false` and `userInteractionIsEnabled` to `false` result both in the button not receiving the `pan events`. I can achieve the desired effect with a custom view, but can I do it somehow with the button.
Posting code snippet with button creation as requested:

```
func createAnswerButton() {
    let width : CGFloat = 154
    let height : CGFloat = 60
    let originX = (view.frame.size.width - width) / 2
    let originY = startOverButton.frame.origin.y + collectionView.frame.size.height
    let frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: width, height: height)
    let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
    answerButton = button
    button.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.answerButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    let image = UIImage(named: "item_neutral")
    button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(button)

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: (#selector(MoviesViewController.didPanButton(_:))))
    button.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
}
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use a `UIButton` instead of a `UIView`?

Comment: I wanted to continue using the title and imageView properties - before the button had also an action attached to it, but no need for it anymore. But I guess this is not a good reason, just laziness, I'll go with the view.

Comment: Can you provide the code snippet?

Comment: @Aditya Provided code snippet for button creation

Comment: You want the button no to fade out when tapped, but still receive tap gestures as well as pan ones?

Comment: @TigranIskandaryan I want it to Not fade out when tapped - just like when tapping a view - nothing to happen, but still receive a pan gesture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this, you have to set the `adjustsImageWhenHighlighted` of the button to `false` (if you want to do it programatically). In interface builder you can change the button `type` to `custom`.

Here is the code for doing this programatically:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    let width : CGFloat = 154
    let height : CGFloat = 60
    let originX = (view.frame.size.width - width) / 2
    let originY = (view.frame.size.height - width) / 2
    let frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: width, height: height)

    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    button.frame = frame

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonInCodeTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.addGestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(panForButtonInCode(recognizer:))))
    button.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "X"), for: .normal)
    view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Here is the result when that property is set to `false`:
  [image]

And here is the result when that property is set to `true` (You can see that when tapped the `X` gets highlighted):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

pretty much you gotta say the button to prefer one gesture over another

for example :

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, 
      shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer:  UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    // Don't recognize a single tap until a double-tap fails.
     if gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture && 
      otherGestureRecognizer == self.doubleTapGesture {
  return true
```

}
      return false
}

for more information follow the link :

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
func createAnswerButton() {
        let width : CGFloat = 154
        let height : CGFloat = 60
        let originX = (view.frame.size.width - width) / 2
        let originY = startOverButton.frame.origin.y + collectionView.frame.size.height
        let frame = CGRect(x: originX, y: originY, width: width, height: height)
        let button = UIButton(frame: frame)
        answerButton = button
        button.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.answerButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        let image = UIImage(named: "item_neutral")
        button.setBackgroundImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanGesture))
        button.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
    @objc func handlePanGesture(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
        print("Pan Gesture detected")
        var buttonCenter : CGPoint = button.center
        if sender?.state == .began {
            buttonCenter = button.center
        } else if sender?.state == .ended || sender?.state == .failed || sender?.state == .cancelled {
            button.center = buttonCenter
        } else {
            let location = sender?.location(in: view)
            button.center = location!
        }
        print("\(buttonCenter)")
    }
    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton){
        print("Button Click detected")
    }
```